# Why does Angular Material starter app's HTML code result in a different layout from what is shown in the readme?

Tags: html, css, angular-material

[Angular Material Starter app](https://github.com/angular/material-start)'s HTML results in a full-height Sidenav that covers the toolbar instead of staying below it.

Layout resulting from the app's code:
[image: Layout resulting from the app's code]

Layout shown in the app's readme:
[image: Layout shown in the app's readme]

Has the behavior of the Sidenav component been changed since this tutorial app was created? What is the way to get the layout shown in the readme?

For quick reference, here is the HTML structure of the app:

```html
<body ng-app="starterApp" layout="column">

    <!-- Container #1 (see wireframe) -->
    <md-toolbar layout="row" >
      <h1>Angular Material - Starter App</h1>
    </md-toolbar>

    <!-- Container #2 -->
    <div flex layout="row">

        <!-- Container #3 -->
        <md-sidenav md-is-locked-open="true" class="md-whiteframe-z2"></md-sidenav>

        <!-- Container #4 -->
        <md-content flex id="content"></md-content>

    </div>

  </body>
```

Comment: Could you do a CodePen with the app code and markup?

Comment: Is it possible to add folders to Codepen? FYI, al the app code and resources are shared at https://github.com/angular/material-start

Comment: Ah, OK. I'll see if I can get it into CodePen tomorrow for a better look.

Comment: I've also filed an issue for this abnormal behavior at the app's github repository but no one has responded yet: https://github.com/angular/material-start/issues/137